# How do I find frequency of Authors and plot this using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, visualization

Here `ABC news` is observed 5 times but the column `Times` reflects it as `1` for each row. Expected output is `ABC news` one time in each row, but the total in `Times` as 5, since ABC has overall published 5 titles.

So that while plotting `Author` is on X-axis, and associated `Times` it has been published, is on Y-axis.

Code for the below dataframe that needs to be changed like mentioned above:

```
a=df1.groupby(['author','title'])['title'].count().reset_index(name="Time")
a.head()



    author                    title                               Time
0   ABC News    WATCH: How to get the most bang for your buck ...   1
1   ABC News    WATCH: Man who confessed to killing wife, chil...   1
2   ABC News    WATCH: Nearly 1,000 still missing 11 days afte...   1
3   ABC News    WATCH: Teen hockey player skates after brain i...   1
4   ABC News    WATCH: Trump: Will not do in-person interview ...   1
5   Ali Dukakis and Mike Levine     Mueller  'has no eff...         1
```

Answer (score 0):

Following shall keep updating your `Times` column with appropriate numbers. You may opt to declare the loop within a function to reuse later on.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( data=[['ABC News','WATCH: How to get the most bang for your buck...','1'], ['ABC News','WATCH: Man who confessed to killing wife, chil...','1'], ['ABC News','WATCH: Nearly 1,000 still missing 11 days afte...','1'], ['ABC News','WATCH: Teen hockey player skates after brain i...','1'], ['ABC News','WATCH: Trump: Will not do in-person interview ...','1'], ['Ali Dukakis and Mike Levine',"Mueller  'has no eff...",'1'] ], columns=['author','title','Times'])

word_count = dict(df['author'].value_counts())
for i,v in df["author"].iteritems():
    if v in word_count.keys():
        df.loc[i, "Times"] = word_count[v]

print(df)
```

This shall get your desired result like: [image]

Plotting `author` against `Times` now shouldn't be an issue, I believe. Kindly accept the answer if it meets your requirement or else please let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are grouping on 'title' when you want to only group by 'author', it seems. Remove 'title' from groupby.